# Before insert trigger not storing values

Tags: trigger

I have a simple trigger that fills a Date field on my customised SObject Segmentacao__c:

```
trigger SegmentacaoPreencheMesDeReferencia on Segmentacao__c (before insert) {
  final Date today = System.today();
  for( Segmentacao__c lSeg : Trigger.new )lSeg.Mes_de_referencia_data__c = today;
}
```

and the following test class:

```
@isTest
private class SegmentacaoPreencheMesDeReferenciaTest {

  static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    Profile admin = SObjectInstance.perfilAdmin();

    User accUser = SObjectInstance.usuario( admin.Id );
    System.assert( Database.insert( accUser, false ).isSuccess() );

    Account acc = SObjectInstance.conta();
    acc.Territorio__c = accUser.Territorio__c;
    System.assert( Database.insert( acc, false ).isSuccess() );

    Segmentacao__c seg = SObjectInstance.segmentacao( acc.Id );
    System.assert( Database.insert( seg, false ).isSuccess() );
    System.debug( '@@@ ' + seg.Mes_de_referencia_data__c + ' ' + System.today() );
    System.assert( seg.Mes_de_referencia_data__c == System.today() );
  }
}
```

My code fails at the last assertion, as `seg.Mes_de_referencia_data__c` is null even when the trigger has been run:

`18:03:53.135 (2135306000)|USER_DEBUG|[27]|DEBUG|@@@ null 2013-05-22 00:00:00`

Is there anything I am missing out?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should query the record again before the last assert to confirm that it has been updated correctly by the trigger.

Comment: This. :) I was just typing the same thing.